# Fastlane issue in Visual Studio Mac XamarinForms

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, fastlane

I've already developed a mobile application using Xamarin Forms and this works properly in the Android and IOs using a device emulator. Now it's time to test this on the physical devices... In Android 100% working.. but on IOs when I will add my apple account in the Visual Studio provisioning profile, I'm getting a Fastlane not installed error pop up, but the fast lane already installed, and this works fine in Xcode, but don't in the Visual Studio... A signing certificate is provided and works, but on click plus button to add account Apple developer account the error is raised. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using latest VS? You can check VS logs and/or report error to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com

Comment: Can you post more details like version numbers, the logs, the full error message, other details that might help please?